# How to check element should be disabled in robot framework?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, robotframework

```
<a class="paginate_button previous disabled" aria-controls="DataTables_Table_82" data-dt-idx="0" tabindex="-1" id="DataTables_Table_82_previous">Previous</a>

*** Test Cases ***
check the preview and next button in the table
       element should be disabled    //*[text()='Previous']
```

This "element should be disabled" keyword always failed and throws element was enabled. There is any method available to do this verify.

Comment: `element should be disabled` this keyword internally checks for attribute `readonly` to be None, but there is no attribute `readonly` in the given html hence it returns false and hence the assertion error

Comment: so there is any method available to verify above test case

Comment: The workaround would be observe the DOM while enabling and disabling the element. Now if any attribute of elements changing use them in the locator and assert on locator. If no attribute changes but new tag or element is added use that in locator and assert on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said in the comments the Element Should Be Disabled keyword checks for an attribute your element does not have. This can happen pretty often with other keywords as well, depending on application you are testing.

In such cases it is advised to create an extra layer on top of SeleniumLibrary that handles the unique aspects of the page elements in your application. This could be a resource file or a library as well.

As it seems your element has a class `class="paginate_button previous disabled"`, `disabled` that could be used to check if the element itself is disabled or not.

For example you could use an XPATH like this `//*[text()='Previous' and contains(@class, 'disabled')]`:

```py
Element Status Should Be Disabled 
    [arguments]    ${element_text}
    Element Should Be Visible    //*[text()='${element_text}' and contains(@class, 'disabled')]
```

To check if the element is enabled you could negate the class criteria or if there is a class called `enabled`, you could check for that in the same way.

```py
Element Status Should Be Enabled
    [arguments]    ${element_text}
    Element Should Be Visible    //*[text()='Previous' and not(contains(@class, 'disabled'))]
```

Note that these keywords are just examples and were written without knowing your application, just to give you an idea.